# How do I pilot the behemoth?

Tags: battlefield-1

When a behemoth pops out on the map for my team how do I get in it and how many spots are available?

I have looked for the spawn vehicle behemoth on the deployment map and attempted to run up to one and get in but I must have been doing it wrong or it is full.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it when on deployment map, by clicking on it. You'll then spawn in it directly, on an available seat.
There are three kinds of behemoths:

- Dreadnought (4 seats, including driver)
- Armored Train (6 seats)
- Airship L30 (6 seats including captain)

I found some links that can help you out:

- [Youtube video](https://youtu.be/pJaN3Q-1gLY) that shows at 0:10 how to take control of the dreadnought.
- [Primagames guide](https://www.primagames.com/games/battlefield-1/tips/battlefield-1-all-behemoth-locations) that explains what are the behemoths in BF1, what they are used for and how you can control them. It also explains where to find each kind of behemoth, in all the available maps and how many spots they have for players.

Comment: I have seen Trains with only 4 seats, like on the City map (whatever its name is)